# I'm getting 503 connection failed errors from DISQUS

Tags: disqus

I recently integrated **DISQUS** commenting system to my blog (not wordpress, blogger or any other kind). I imported my previous comments as **WXR** xml file to **DISQUS**. Whenever I go to the post I see **DISQUS** is successfully showing all the comments but when I look into firebug I see some polling (XHR requests) is happening in the background on the two URLs http://realtime.services.disqus.com/api/2/thread/XXXXXXX and http://qq.disqus.com/1334752299515229035/XXXXXXX/ and the requests are getting failed by `503` errors.

The interesting thing is this is happening only from my machine not from others. From other machines I don't see even any requests firing up. Can any body please help me why this is happening?

**UPDATE**: I can reproduce the issue in other machines as well, it occurs once the user has commented for a post. It's really driving me nuts!

Here is the firebug screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DISQUS frequently poll their servers to load the comments and this polling happens only if someone has commented from their machine. In my office machine, due to some slow connection or connection settings I'm getting the "503 connection errors".